# No CPU and Memory in Debug Navigator in Xcode when iPhone is connected

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

When I run app on simulator in Debug Navigator I have CPU and Memory.
But when I connect iPhone and run app on device I do not have CPU and Memory in Debug Navigator.

I have Xcode 5.0.2 and iPhone 4 with iOS 6.1.2

Do I need to enable it some how, or iPhone is just to old ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You iPhone device is old, memory show from at least iOS 7